# Selecting currently active method in Structure pane in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, when I'm looking at my code and have the Structure pane open listing all the classes, methods and member variables, it would be nice if IntelliJ could automatically highlight the name of the method that my cursor is located in within the code window. As it stands, I have to manually scroll to the start of the method to figure out the name and then look in the Structure pane to figure out where it is located when I need to navigate back to it when I scroll my code window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The toolbar of the Structure pane has a button called "Autoscroll from source". Pushing it will give you the behavior you want.

Comment: As silly as it sounds, just to add to yole's command, there are two buttons in the Structure panel for auto-scrolling.  One is "Autoscroll from Source" and the other is "Autoscroll to Source".  Don't make the mistake I did and keep pressing the "Autoscroll to Source" and start to think that yole's answer is invalid.  I hope this saves you 30 seconds :)